# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method "slimScroll"

Tags: jquery

I using slimScroll to create nice scollbar but it doesnt work. How to fix this? I got error and see this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgkbQ.png

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#scroll-bussiness').slimscroll({
        height: '200px',
        size: '2px',
        color: '#333'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: are the library files loading without error?

Comment: only clue here is `js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js`  is it ok ?I mean the path.

Comment: @Sergio Yes,I checked the both. :)

Comment: Try `.slimScroll({`, with big "S"

Comment: Its correct path to the file and I changed it to slimScroll but still get same error.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a fiddle, or post a live link to your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin name is case sensitive, please try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#scroll-bussiness').slimScroll({
        height: '200px',
        size: '2px',
        color: '#333'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpT2/

Comment: I thought it would also, but it makes no difference. Check here http://jsfiddle.net/k3LJg/

Comment: Im not sure why but it still doesnt work for me. Maybe my site use many js and they are conflict

Comment: You may have errors in other parts of your code? The solution above works as shown in the jsFiddle. Good luck!